# How to completely uninstall the standalone (appimage) app called Etcher from Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, appimage

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I downloaded and installed Etcher for Linux x64 (64-bit) (AppImage), a standalone application to make bootable USB drives.

Supposedly, to uninstall the application I simply have to remove it. However, on first use a message popped up asking:

> Should a desktop file for `/home/myhome/Downloads/etcher-electron-1.4.4-x86_64.AppImage` be installed?

I selected *Yes*, and now I can't get the message to come back. I deleted the AppImage file and extracted a new one from the downloaded zip file, but the message will no longer pop up. This seems to indicate that the application has not completely removed. How do I completely remove it?

For those claiming this is a duplicate, the answer to the provided "duplicate" does not apply here because this is a standalone application. Please read more carefully next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you click "yes" to that message, a file called `appimagekit-Etcher.desktop` (or similar) is created in the following location:

```
/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/
```

To completely remove Etcher you have to remove the etcher .AppImage file as you described, and you should also remove this .desktop file. To do this, run the command:

```
rm /home/<username>/.local/share/applications/appimagekit-Etcher.desktop
```

replacing  with the actual name of your home directory. Optionally, you can remove only this file if you just want to see the message again.

Comment: Appimage apps also create /home/[username]/.config/[appname] directory. You might want to delete it if you don't aim to reinstall the app or want it completely removed. So combining all three answers:

`sudo rm /path/to/app.appimage` then
`sudo rm /home/<username>/.local/share/applications/<app.appimage>`
then if you want to remove config files:
`sudo rm -r /home/<username>/.config/<appimage>`